# Regex - Extracting PubMed publications via Beautiful Soup, identify authors from my list that appear in PubMed article, and add bold HTML tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm working with a project where we are web-scraping PubMed research abstracts and detecting if any researchers from our organization have authorship on any new publications. When we detect a match, we want to add a bold HTML tag.  For example, you might see something like this is PubMed: **Sanjay Gupta** 1 2 3, **Mehmot Oz** 3 4, Terry Smith 2 4 (the numbers denote their academic affiliation, which corresponds to a different field, but I've left this out for simplicity.  If Mehmot Oz and Sanjay Gupta were in my list, I would add a bold tag before their first name and a tag to end the bold at the end of their name.

One of my challenges with PubMed is the authors sometimes only show their first and last name, other times it includes a middle initial (e.g., Sanjay K Gupta versus just Sanjay Gupta). In my list of people, I only have first and last name.  What I tried to do is import my list of names, split first and last name, and then bold them in the list of authors.  The problem is that my code will bold anyone with the first name or anyone with the last name (example: **Sanjay** Smith 1 2 3, **Sanjay Gupta** 1 3 4, Wendy **Gupta** 4 5 6, Linda **Oz** 4,  **Mehmet** Jones 5, **Mehmet Oz** 1 4 6.) gets bolded.  I realize the flaw in my code, but I'm struggling for how to get around this.  Any help is appreciated.

**Bottom Line**: I have a list of people by first name and last name, I want to find their publications in PubMed and bold their name in the author credits.  PubMed sometimes has their first and last name, but sometimes their middle initial.

To make things easier, I denoted the section in all caps for the part in my code where I need help.

```
import time
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

all_pmids = []
out = []
base_urls = ['https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=sanjay+gupta&filter=years.2021-2021','https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=AHRQ+Diabetes+telehealth&filter=years.2016-2016', 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=mehmet+oz&filter=years.2020-2020']

author_list = ['Mehmet Oz', 'Sanjay Gupta', 'Ken Jeong', 'Susie Bates', 'Vijay Singh', 'Cynthia Berg']

for search_url in base_urls:
    
    response = requests.get(search_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    pmids = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'docsum-pmid'})
    for p in pmids:
        p = p.get_text()
        all_pmids.append(p) if p not in all_pmids else print(p + ' already in list, skipping')
        
for pmid in all_pmids:

    url = 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/'+pmid
    response2 = requests.get(url)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup2.select('h1.heading-title')[0].text.strip() if soup2.find(class_='item-list') is not None else ''

    #THIS IS THE START OF THE SECTION I NEED HELP WITH  
    authors = soup2.find(class_='authors-list').get_text(' ') if soup2.find(class_='authors-list') is not None else ''
    authors = authors.rstrip() if soup2.find(class_='authors-list') is not None else ''
    authors = " ".join(authors.split()) if soup2.find(class_='authors-list') is not None else ''
    
    for au in author_list:
        au_l = au.split()[1] + ' '
        au_f = au.split()[0] + ' '

        authors = re.sub(au_f, '<b>'+au_f, authors) if '<b>' + au_f not in authors else authors
        authors = re.sub(au_l, au_l+'</b>', authors) if '</b>' + au_l not in authors else authors
    #THIS IS THE END OF THE SECTION I NEED HELP WITH
    data = {'title': title, 'authors': authors}
    time.sleep(5)
    out.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(out)

df.to_excel('my_output.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modification that needs to be done in the section you want help with.
Here is the algorithm:

1. Create list of authors by splitting on `,`
2. For each author in authors, check if au_l and au_f are present in author.
3. If true, add `<b>` tags

```
#THIS IS THE START OF THE SECTION I NEED HELP WITH
authors = None
if (authors_html := soup2.find(class_='authors-list')):
    authors = authors_html.get_text(' ')
if not authors:
    continue
authors = " ".join(authors.rstrip().split()).split(",")

for au in author_list:
    au_f, au_l = au.split()
    for i in range(len(authors)):
        if au_f in authors[i] and au_l in authors[i]:
            authors[i] = f"<b> {authors[i]} <b>"

#THIS IS THE END OF THE SECTION I NEED HELP WITH
    data = {'title': title, 'authors': ",".join(authors)}
```

Also, made some minor updates to improve readability.

Comment: You made my day, heck you made my weekend.  Thanks for the help and providing some cleaner changes.  This is the best way to learn and get better. I really appreciate it.